I added Java keystore certs in intellij, it overriden github certs and I am getting handshake errors when I try to fetch or update from Github
Initially my Java app had some handshake issues. I figured my Java app is missing some Java certs to make connections to my API's , I had to update some Java Keystore Trust certs in application also update IntelliJ proxy configs. By adding this my Java application started working but my Github started to give handshake errors.
Seems like somehow my certificate got corrupted.
How can I reset the intellij certs?
Things I tried

invalidate cache

Reset IDE

Deleted App data file and reloaded workspace. Still I get SSL handshake errors from Github.


How can I reset intellij certs, so I can fetch the code from github and other API's so I can resolve sslhandshakeexception from github in intellij.
somehow my STS also seems to stop working in got fetch. I had to manually use CMD to perform git operations. Any help is greatly appreciated!
